# PHP redirect user through .htaccess and pass requested URL to php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Say I'm trying to access:

```
mysite.com/foo/bar/
```

I want too:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Then:

```
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo $url;
```

To show:

```
foo/bar/
```

Currently getting:

```
index.php
```

(Obviously I have no idea, but you get the point for what I'm trying to achieve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php